# How to refer to font file inside a Confluence plugin?

Tags: plugins, fonts, confluence

I want a text use specific font style, I assign its CSS class as ".title" and the related code all are declared in a CSS file within a Confluence plugin as following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(MyriadPro-Regular.otf) format("opentype"), local("Consolas");
}

.title {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
}
```

But the plugin cannot find the font file. The font file is in the same folder with the CSS file. 
**What should be the url for the font file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Confluence Server, a basic plugin could be defined like so:

With some files in the following structure:

```
/your-plugin-name/
/your-plugin-name/main
/your-plugin-name/main/java
/your-plugin-name/main/resources
/your-plugin-name/main/resources/atlassian-plugin.xml
/your-plugin-name/main/resources/css/custom.css
/your-plugin-name/main/resources/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf
```

And an `atlassian-plugin.xml` like this:

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
  </plugin-info>

  <web-resource key="your-web-resources" name="Web Resources">

    <resource name="style.css"  type="download" location="css/custom.css" />
    <resource name="myriad.otf" type="download" location="fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf" />

    <!-- Adding main & global contexts means that these web resources will always be loaded. -->
    <context>main</context>
    <context>global</context>

  </web-resource>

</atlassian-plugin>
```

Your CSS and font files will be available globally throughout Confluence.

Your CSS file will automatically be loaded and be named something like `/downloads/gfdsgfdsgf/fdsgfd/me.davidsimpson.confluence.plugins.example:your-web-resources/style.css` where `gfdsgfdsgf/fdsgfd` is some random characters.

You should be able to reference your font files as though they are in the same directory as the css file like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(myriad.otf) format("opentype"), local("Consolas");
}

.title {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
}
```

..but note that they have new names - `style.css` & `myriad.otf`.

Answer (score 1):

### For Confluence Server

If you want something like Consolas to work in Confluence, you'd either need to ensure that the font is installed on all browsers, or use a similar web font such as [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata).

If you're happy that everyone has the correct font installed, add the following to

**Confluence Admin | Custom HTML | At the END of the HEAD**:

```
<style> body { font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace; } </style>
```

If you decide to use the web font, add the following to

**Confluence Admin | Custom HTML | At the END of the HEAD**:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<style> body { font-family: Inconsolata, Consolas, monaco, monospace; } </style>
```

These assume that you want to use the [Consolas font stack](http://www.cssfontstack.com/Consolas) - where a similar font will be used if the Consolas/Inconsolata font fails to load.

### For Confluence Cloud

You cannot edit CSS or add markup to the page, so this is not possible.

Comment: Hi dvdsmps, is your answer for Confluence global setting?
    
The text is generated from a plugin, is it possible to use the same way in plugin to display designate font?

Comment: If you want to do it in a plugin, add the <link ...> in a web-panel module instead or use a web resource module to add local css which bundles the content of the remote CDs file. That way, whenever the plugin is used, the styles will be applied

Comment: Hi dvdsmps, I put the font file in the resources folder, and add this line `url(/download/resources/com.xyz.org/MyriadPro-Regular.otf)` in the css file. And check the text with the Chrome developer tool, its font is Myriad Pro, but actually it looks not Myriad Pro font. Is there something wrong or missed?

Comment: Hi dvdsmps, I update my question, could you please give me some advices? Thank you.